# Can an Indian citizen visit India with less than 6 months passport validity left?

Tags: passports, indian-citizens, india, uae

I am an Indian citizen working in Abu Dhabi. I plan to visit my family in India for one month in June 2023. My passport expires on 25th Sept 2023, appx 3 months after my arrival.

Will I be allowed to enter India? Will I be able to exit and return to Abu Dhabi after my vacation in June?

Comment: You have a residence permit for UAE?

Answer (score 3):

As your passport is valid India is going to let you in. As far as I understand the country will also let you travel out with only a few months left on your passport.

But check whether you will be allowed back into Abu Dhabi after your travel, they might require a longer period on your passport, not sure, you may have a different entry proof that does not require your passport to have extra time.

When in India you may want to apply for a new passport, that way you will not have the risk of 'not enough time left'. In that case check that your visa or whatever you have for Abu Dhabi will be valid with a new passport.

Answer (score 2):

India isn't what you should be concerned about, they will let you in. The UAE though, does require **6 months passport validity at the time of entry** (ie when you come back). According to the [UK's travel advice though](https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/united-arab-emirates/entry-requirements#:%7E:text=Passport%20validity,to%20travel%20to%20the%20UAE.), this requirement is shortened to **3 months for those holding UAE residence permits**.

[image: UAE PASS]